# Javascript: how to create an object with numeric String keys

Tags: javascript

I need to create an object in javascript, similar to the following structure:

```
{ 
  '1': { 
    'key1-1': 'val1-1',
    'key-1-2': 'val1-2'
  }, 
  '2': { 
    'key1-1': 'val1-1',
    'key1-2': 'val1-2'
  }
}
```

I tried with Object(); but the key remains the literal name of the variable.

```
> var myObj = new Object();
> for (var i  = 1; i< 5; i++) {
... myObj.i = {'key1-1': 'val1-1',
.....         'key-1-2': 'val1-2'}
... }
> console.log(myObj)
{ i: { 'key1-1': 'val1-1', 'key-1-2': 'val1-2' } }
```

Tried converting the variable i to string but still the same.

```
> for (var i  = 1; i< 5; i++) {
... var iStr = i.toString();
... myObj.iStr = {'key1-1': 'val1-1',
..... 'key-1-2': 'val1-2'}
... }
> console.log(myObj)
{ iStr: { 'key1-1': 'val1-1', 'key-1-2': 'val1-2' } }
```

How can we create a json Object with numeric string keys like '1', '2', '3' ...

Comment: Update from `myObj.i` to `myObj[i]`

Comment: The string conversion happens automatically. Even array indexes are strings. You are using the wrong syntax to define the key.

Comment: **There is no such thing as a *json Object***. You want an object? Then it's Javascript. You want a string representation of that object? Then it's JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two nested for loops along with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make it more generic. And use  the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for creating dynamic properties.

```js
let m = 3;
let n =2;

let result = {};

for(let i = 1; i <=m; i++){
  result[i] = {};
  for(let j = 1; j <=n; j++){
      result[i][`key1-${j}`] = `val1-${j}`;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change myObj.istr to myObj[istr]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp

Another option is use :

myObj[istr] = value

Where istr is a string